# Search tool that shows/scrolls the documents it searches (like the tool from The Matrix)

Tags: gui, search-engine

In the movie [*The Matrix*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix), the character *Neo* is using a program that downloads and searches (newspaper) articles.

The tool has a GUI and it displays and scrolls the document it is currently searching. When the end of this document is reached, it downloads/shows the next one. This process seems to go off automatically, as *Neo* is sleeping meanwhile.

[image: Neo sleeps while a tool on his computer downloads and searches newspaper articles.]

A closer look at the GUI shows a toolbar, a download progress bar (top right), and the document area (which scrolls down automatically) with the status label "Searching…".

[image: GUI of Neo’s searching tool]

**Is there a (similar) tool like this?**

A simple **keyword search** is sufficient.

The tool must **show** and automatically **scroll** the document it is currently searching. As this would probably take less than a second per document, it should **slow down** somewhat, so that human observers can follow the search.

Bonus points for **highlighting sentences/paragraphs** the tool is currently searching. Even more bonus points for using **OCR**.

It would be great if the tool really **downloads** documents from the Internet (e.g., using [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) in the background), but searching **local** documents only is okay, too.

I don’t want to give file format requirements, but it should at least support a **document type** that allows to embed images and/or supports formatted text. HTML and PDF would be great.

I don’t care about platform/price/license.

Comment: Fun question. How would you specify which documents to look into? List of folder/filepaths? Note that search engine don't go through the entire documents one by one when answering a query but use some indices.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: If it searches local documents, specifying a folder and/or a file name pattern (for a global search) would be nice; if it searches online, specifying a list of URLs and/or using a "follow hyperlinks" feature (starting from a given URL) would be nice (i.e., like Wget does it). -- But I don’t want to require a specific way, as I fear there won’t be many (if any at all?) tools that use such an ineffectual way of searching.

Comment: @unor I have to ask: for what are you going to use it?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: I hope it will be relaxing and fun to *watch* a search, similar to some mesmerizing screensavers (with the added benefit that it’s actually useful, and that there’s a chance of serendipitous discoveries as it shows you all specified documents, i.e., even those that are not relevant results).

Comment: See also on [movies.se]: [What program is Neo using?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/96852/1876)

Answer (score 3):

This is:

- A command line solution
- Works only for text files
- Works for Linux (and perhaps on Windows, via Cygwin)

  ```
  while read line; do sleep 0.2s; echo "$line" | sed -r 's/word_you_want_to_find/\x1b[31m\1\x1b[0m/g'; done < <(find . -type f -exec cat {} \; )
  ```

... will do what you want.

- You can control the speed by modifying the interval of `sleep` (I've used 0.2 seconds).
- You can search for multiple words by using `(word1|word2|word3)` in place of `word_you_want_to_find`.
- You can specify filename patterns too, for example, by using `find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} \;`.

Answer (score 3):

I have developed a web application like this, it is basically a web crawler that shows the relevant pages that it finds during it's crawl. You search by entering keywords, giving them weights and set a minimum relevance score for what websites that should be shown.

All the websites are shown in iframes so you can fully interact with them meanwhile the search goes on.

[image]

The source code can be found here: https://github.com/spydon/fetchur